# Apache 2.4 .htaccess RewriteRule with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have try to update apache from 2.2 to 2.4 after all i have problem to get some part of site to working on new apache. I have search function and htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?mode=search&q=%1&type=videos [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search/photos$ index.php?mode=search&q=%1&type=photos [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^search$ search.php [QSA,L]
```

Where I'm make mistake? On apache 2.2 this lines is working fine but on 2.4 is back me blank page and no errors in logs.

Comment: That sounds a lot more likely to be a PHP error than an Apache one, in which case we have no way of guessing from what you've shown us. You need to find or configure your PHP error logs.

Comment: But url without rewriting is working fine `index.php?mode=search&q=%1&type=videos`

Comment: @mlinnko, thanks you for sharing your efforts in your question, could you please do mention a sample link which is working in older version and not working in newer version? That will give us better understanding of your question

Comment: sure `https://example.com/search?q=term` and for photos `https://example.com/search/photos?q=term`

Comment: @mlinnko, Rules are looking ok to me, could you please add a line `---------` in your htaccess once and after saving your file try hitting any url once? If its giving 500 internal error then it means your htaccess is enabled else its not, please do it once and confirm how it goes, thank you. NOTE: Please tag people using @ else they will not get notification(Like I am doing to you now), like I haven't received notification for your comment.

Comment: Fixed, apache 2.4 MultiViews enabled somewhere by default, this was creating problem

Comment: @mlinnko, that was not shown in your questions htaccess, thanks for sharing. You could add it as an answer in here so that future readers can get benifit cheers

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, apache 2.4 MultiViews enabled by default, this was creating problem. After disabling **MultiViews** search and rewrite working  as expected.